# smiley popup window is not closing automatically after sending message

Tags: cometchat

In my comet chat application `smiley popup` window is not closing  after sending chat message.Now it can close only manually choose the close button,But in the case of `attachment` it automatically closed after attachment places to chat room.
Is any settings(comet chat admin side) or option for do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting in the backend to do this. This is the normal behaviour. This is there because if the user wishes to type post adding a smiley he can. Otherwise if it closes automatically like attachments then the user will have to again click on the text box area after adding every smiley which is not a user friendly approach thus it behaves differently than how attachment work.